# How do I set a different background to current tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wrote a code for three tab t click to everyone, the content of it will be appear.

but I have a problem that is I want to put different background for currently tab that is selected but I dont have any idea for it and i don't know about its code .

check out this demo to know well what i created : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JsAmin/52Q4b/)

how can I have sth like this : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JsAmin/52Q4b/) 

,,, when I click to tab , the selected tab will have different background ( red ).
thanks. 

here' my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab ul li:nth-child(1)").click(function () {
        $(".box1").fadeIn();
        $(".box2").hide();
        $(".box3").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab ul li:nth-child(2)").click(function () {
        $(".box2").fadeIn();
        $(".box1").hide();
        $(".box3").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab ul li:nth-child(3)").click(function () {
        $(".box3").fadeIn();
        $(".box1").hide();
        $(".box2").hide();
    });
});
```

Css:

```
.tab {
    margin - left: 2px;
}
.tab ul li {
    background: red;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    border - radius: 3px;
    float: left;
    list - style: none;
    margin - left: 2px;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    height: 190px;
    width: 244px;
    position: relative;
    top: 34px;
    left: 38px;
}
.box1 {
    background: green;
}
.box2 {
    background: blue;
}
.box3 {
    background: yellow;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="tab">
<ul>
    <li>Test Tab 1</li>
    <li>Test Tab 2</li>
    <li>Test Tab 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="box3" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: by the way, you only need `$(document).ready(function(){...}` once. In fact, if you place this script before the `</body>` tag you don't need `.ready()` at-all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52Q4b/2/)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tab ul li:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
          $(".box1").fadeIn();
          $(".box2").hide();
          $(".box3").hide();
          $(".tab ul li").css("background", "red")
          $(this).css("background", "blue")
        });
        $(".tab ul li:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
          $(".box2").fadeIn();
          $(".box1").hide();
          $(".box3").hide();
          $(".tab ul li").css("background", "red")
          $(this).css("background", "blue")
        });
        $(".tab ul li:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
          $(".box3").fadeIn();
          $(".box1").hide();
          $(".box2").hide();
          $(".tab ul li").css("background", "red")
          $(this).css("background", "blue")
        });
    });
```

and add this css

```
.tab ul li:nth-child(1) {
    background: blue;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52Q4b/3/)

Comment: thnks:), If I want to be default blue, I mean this code you gave me , I have to click to one tab to be blue, I want to be blue for default .

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're coding in a procedural mindset: covering all basis and possible outcomes and potentialities (it's a very linear pattern). Sure, it still works, but consequently your code has become very lengthy and thus harder to read and maintain.

### HTML(5)

```
<div class="tab">
    <ul>
        <li data-color="green">Test Tab 1</li>
        <li data-color="blue">Test Tab 2</li>
        <li data-color="yellow">Test Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="box" data-color="green"></div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab ul li").click(function(){       
        $(".tab ul li").removeClass("active")
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('.box').css("background", $(this).data('color'));
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
.tab ul li.active{
    background: purple; 
}

.box{
    height: 190px;
    width: 244px;
    position: relative;
    top: 34px;
    left: 38px;
    background: green;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fg5L8/)**

Comment: Its good suggestion, Can you please update your code. If there have three different boxes, with different content.

Comment: I will keep the answer as is, as it pertains to the question. However, i have made a [basic jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar5Qy/) for you with the fundamental logic behind it.